# Probability of seeds germinating

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

Suppose that the probability that a new seed planted in a specific farm germinates is equal to the proportion of all planted seeds that germinated in that farm previously. Suppose that the first seed planted in the farm germinated, but the second seed planted did not germinate. For positive integers n and k (k < n), what is the probability that of the first n seeds planted in the farm exactly k germinated?

Answer:

Let p(k, n) be the probability that exactly k of the first n seeds planted in the farm germinated. Using induction on n,we will show that $p(k,n)=\frac{1}{(n−1)}$ for all k< n.

For n=2, $p(1,2)=1=\frac{1}{(2−1)}$ is true. If $p(k,n−1)=\frac{1}{(n−2)}$ for all k< n-1 then, by the law of total probability,

$$\begin{align}p(k,n)&= \frac{k-1}{n-1}p(k-1,n-1)+\frac{n-k-1}{n-1}p(k,n-1)\\&=\frac{k-1}{n-1}\frac{1}{n-2}+\frac{n-k-1}{n-1}\frac{1}{n-2}=\frac{1}{n-1}\end{align}$$

I would like to see why the formula is true without trying out on a few small cases and seeing that they are all $\frac{1}{n-1}$ and then verifying by induction.

Comment: I can make the observation that the problem is symmetric. Asking for the probability of $k$ seeds germinating is the same as asking for the probability of $k$ seeds **not** germinating. But the probability of $k$ seeds not germinating is the same as the probability of $n-k$ seeds germinating. From here we conclude that $p(k, n)=p(n-k, n)$. Using this fact and that $p(1, n)+p(2, n)+\dots +p(n-1, n)=1$, I was thinking of somehow showing that all these events are equally likely, which would lead to $p(k,n)=\frac{1}{n-1}$, but got stuck.